# Using Quartz for long running job

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled, quartz

I'm planning to use Quartz scheduler to process a one-time job.

My use case is, I need to migrate BLOB from one storage to another and blob's can be as big as 100GB, so a particular job can run really long enough to get the work done.

The reason I'm using Quartz because of its clustering support, fault tolerance and retry capabilities in case job fails etc. Only thing I'm concerned about is, I might have a lot of miss fire trigger scenario and a lot of database lock which can hamper live production traffic on those database hosts. I will probably be scheduling 10s of thousands of job in one shot.

Few of the things that I figured out is

- I can set a high value for `org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold` so that miss fire does not happen. I don't really care about the time when the job get's picked up as it's background job and no SLA as such. Only thing I care about is that eventually job getting picked up and getting work done.
- I can also set batch mode properties `org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount` and `org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow`. I understand the batch max count property should be like equal to the thread pool size which can give the biggest bang on performance but what should be the value of fire ahead of time window be?
- I'm using Quartz with Spring boot and will be leveraging `org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT`. What I understand is execute method of the job get wrapped in the transaction, will this cause any problem since transaction will be open for a long time as the job might take hours to complete? Is this something ok? I will be using Oracle database.

Am I missing something here? Can someone share their experience with a similar use case?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by i will schedule 10s of thousands of job in one shot? My understanding of your use case is, you need to transfer large amount of data from one location to another. So you are planning to split them into smaller tasks and execute it using quartz. If so, one thing you can do just schedule a recurring job that will know where to start and will persist what it has successfully worked on so that next run can start from there. It could be starting row id and number of rows to process in each run.

Comment: Your understanding is bang on. When I say need to migrate 10s of thousands, I mean request to migrate data will be in incremental fashion like migrate from range 10 - 10000. When this request comes, I will create individual Quartz job for each of those records i.e. JobDataMap will contain the row id that needs to be migrated. This way I don't need to maintain another table that will keep information about what was migrated and what is left. Makes sense?

Comment: You don't need another table to maintain progress information. You can use the same jobDataMap to persist that information. You just need to annotate your job class with "@PersistJobDataAfterExecution". Look at this for an example http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example4.html

Comment: You're right. With this approach, I can just have one job that will work in a recurring manner but with this approach, I will not be able to horizontally scale my jobs (by adding more machine running slave node of Quartz scheduler) since only one instance will be ever be allowed to run.

Comment: You will be limited to single instance only if your jobs are annotated with "DisallowConcurrentExecution". However the PersistJobDataAfterExecution may not help if you have multiple instances run in parallel as you might have to synchronize the work load outside of quartz.

Comment: DisallowConcurrentExecution works on the basis of `org.quartz.utils.Key.JobKey`. I can always define a unique job which can be something like primaryKeyOfRecord+JobGroup, that way I can make sure I will be able to run different multiple ids in parallel but not allowing job with same job key. That's why I was going by the approach when I said I will schedule 10s of thousands of those jobs. I hope it is making sense now.